# Programmatic Creation of Chart and setting of its legends

Tags: c#, winforms-interop

I am creating Charts pie, bar and line and want to set their Legends along with valuea,Title of legend and point the values on Charts. how could i do so?

Comment: There are thousands of examples around. What did you do what did you try? We will help but we won't write the code for you.

Comment: Fine Sir! Thanks for the reply. Sir I am trying to set the Title on the Legends of pie Chart but my code couldn't work. kindly just tell me how to set the Title on Legends of the Pie Chart? Programmatically.

Comment: A good way to learn about Chart details is to do it in the designer and then look at the reuslts in the designer.cs file. Example : `legend1.Title = "some text";`

Comment: Not working Sir. this is how i do.


Chart addchart()
        {
            Legend legend = new Legend();
            Chart chartA = new Chart();
            chartA.BackColor = Color.White;         
            chartA.Width = 370;
            chartA.Height = 250;
                          
                chartA.Location = new Point(480, 35);
                chartA.Name = "" + textBox1.Text.ToString();
                chartA.Legends.Add(new Legend("" + textBox1.Text.ToString()));
                legend.Title = "Age of The Employees";
}

Comment: You should have posted the code right from the start. Also it ought to be in the question, not a comment.. - To fix your ussues see my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't need to add a `Legend` as there is already  a default one. But since you are creating a `Chart` in code you indeed have to code a little more. Adding a `Legend` is **one** of thoses things.

You have created a `legend` but instead of adding it you create another legend still. Instead write: `chartA.Legends.Add(legend)`

Note that the documentation (including Intellisense) is wrong on the [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.legend.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2) with a string paramenter! It works as expected, not as documented on MSDN!

What I suggested (`chartA.Legends[0].Title = "someString";`) works fine provided you have done all the other things you need:

You will also have to create (at least)

- One `ChartArea`
- One `Series` along with the `ChartType`you want an..
- ..in order to make it show you also have to add a `DataPoint`.

Example:

```
Legend legend = new Legend();
Chart chartA = new Chart();     // <<---!
chartA.BackColor = Color.White;
chartA.Width = 370;
chartA.Height = 250;
chartA.Location = new Point(48, 35);
chartA.Name = textBox1.Text;
chartA.Legends.Add(legend);     // <<---!
legend.Title = "Age of The Employees";     // <<---!

chartA.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea("ca"));     // <<---!
chartA.ChartAreas["ca"].BackColor = Color.LightSeaGreen;
Series s1 = chartA.Series.Add("s1");     // <<---!
s1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
s1.Points.AddY(12);
s1.Points.AddY(32);
..
```

The first `Legend` will **automatically** be filled with **either** one `LegendItem` per `Series` **or** (if you have a `Pie` chart) one item per `DataPoint`

Btw: You may have additional `Legends` but you will have to take care of their content and their position/docking..

Update: If you want to you can take control of both the Legend's `Font` and the `TitleFont`; It works the usual way, i.e. by creating a new `Font`, either from scratch of from the `FontFamily` of a `Font`:

```
 legend.Font = new Font("Consolas", 10f);
 legend.TitleFont = new Font(legend.Font.FontFamily, 14f);
```

You may want to insert a newline character (`\n`) into the title if it is too long to fit into a vertical Legend..

Comment: Could you please tell me how could set the Font of the Title. its coming too big.

Comment: If you are happy with an answer, please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..!

Comment: Sorry! Sir To Disturb you again. Sir, Want to know how can I make the focus of the chart on the front if selected. What happening now is a chart created after another chart appears in the back of created before. and how can i set the block area for new creation? thanks

Comment: I don't understand. To change their z-oder you can use BringToFront or SendToBack. - By default controls you add are on top of those that were added before. You don't show any code of how and where you add your charts, so I can't say. Btw: there seeems to be no reason to tag the question with `winforms-interop`. Do replace by `winforms` and `mschart` !

Comment: Sir! how could I upload my coad?

Comment: You can't. Edit the question to include the relevant parts ie the parts that add the chart to some container..

Comment: Sir! what should i do now? Should i commit the coad?